# Make App Activities and States Searchable by using NSUserActivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, nsuseractivity

Following is the code that I am trying to implement to make app activities and states searchable but not able to show on iOS search

```
NSUserActivity *userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc]initWithActivityType:@"com.mycompany.activity-type"];

userActivity.title = @"Hello world from in app search";
userActivity.keywords = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"Hello",@"Welcome", @"search"]];
userActivity.userInfo = @{@"id":@"com.example.state"};

userActivity.eligibleForSearch = YES;    
[userActivity becomeCurrent];
```

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW2) to make my question more clear.

Comment: Have you tried it after integraton Core Spotlight API as well?

Comment: Yup I have added CoreSpotLight and MobileCoreServices

Comment: Okay. So you have implemented all required core spotlight method? I know its not required but Apple recommends it to work with NSUserActivity.

Comment: @Ayush, Have you figured it out ?

Comment: have you fixed this? same issue here also

Answer (score 22):

From the Apple Forums:

> One thing that has bitten a few people (myself included) is that the
>   activity must not be deallocated.  If your code is only working with
>   NSUserActivities (i.e. not using CoreSpotlight in addition) then **make**
>   **sure your activities aren't being deallocated immediately**.
>   In my
>   case, I had code that was allocating the NSUA, setting some properties
>   on it, calling becomeCurrent, but then the object would go out of
>   scope and deallocated. If you're doing this, try tossing the activity
>   into a strong property to see if you can then see the results when you
>   search.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/13640#13640

Comment: This totally makes sense. For those of you who created a class just for indexing CoreSpotlight and UserActivity stuff, what I did to solve the problem is creating a static NSMutableArray * activityArray = nil; initializing it in +(void)initialize as an empty mutable array and then adding the activities to it. This might be a bit of an overkill, but it is working so far and I'll make it better later.

Answer (score 6):

What I have found is you have to assign the NSUserActivity instance you have created to your currently visible UIViewControllers's userActivity property before calling -becomeCurrent. It has fixed it for me and the items immediately appeared both for handoff on other devices and in spotlight search on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, and I read on the dev forums that in seed 1 it only works on the device. I was able to make it work on the device.

It might be that this, as with handoff, will only work on the device sadly.

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work, a workaround would be to associate a CSSearchItem with the activity

Answer (score -2):

I couldn't get it to work with beta 2 either.
Using a `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` with

```
CSSearchableItemAttributeSet* attributeSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];
attributeSet.title = myobject.title;
attributeSet.keywords = [myobject.desc componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
attributeSet.contentDescription = myobject.desc;
if (myobject.images.count > 0) {
    attributeSet.thumbnailData = myobject.myimagedata;
}
attributeSet.rating = @(myobject.rating.integerValue / 2);

CSSearchableItem* item;
item = [[CSSearchableItem alloc] initWithUniqueIdentifier:@"..." domainIdentifier:@"..." attributeSet:attributeSet];
[[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] indexSearchableItems:@[item] completionHandler: ^(NSError * __nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"Search item indexed");
}];
```

works, though, even with images.
What I couldn't get to work was the rating to show up anywhere.